# My wi-fi auto connect after very long time (about 5 minutes)

Tags: wireless

Every time I start my computer I have to press twice F12 in order to deactivate and reactivate WI FI, and just after that my connection starts (in a few seconds). Is it a way to make it start automatically?
Complementary info: If I don’t press twice F12, it takes about 5 minutes to auto-connect - as I just discovered
Complementary info: It seems that it was an illusion the fact that pressing twice F12 shorten the connection time. Now every time I have to wait about 5 minutes.

---

[From OP]

```
[  336.774812] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[  336.775300] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[  338.236603] wlan0: authenticate with dc:02:8e:63:b9:10
[  338.244241] wlan0: send auth to dc:02:8e:63:b9:10 (try 1/3)
[  338.245846] wlan0: authenticated
[  338.247641] wlan0: associate with dc:02:8e:63:b9:10 (try 1/3)
[  338.250925] wlan0: RX AssocResp from dc:02:8e:63:b9:10 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=1)
[  338.251034] wlan0: associated
[  338.251059] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
[ 2592.514180] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[ 2696.299008] wlan0: authenticate with dc:02:8e:63:b9:10
[ 2696.308971] wlan0: send auth to dc:02:8e:63:b9:10 (try 1/3)
[ 2696.319632] wlan0: authenticated
[ 2696.320512] wlan0: associate with dc:02:8e:63:b9:10 (try 1/3)
[ 2696.328968] wlan0: RX AssocResp from dc:02:8e:63:b9:10 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=1)
[ 2696.329083] wlan0: associated
[ 2696.329161] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
```

Comment: What is the output of `dmesg | grep wlan`?

Comment: Does "sudo service network-manager restart" start the the connection before 5 minutes have left ?

Comment: It says 'stop: Unknown instance: 
network-manager start/running, process 2601' then is connecting instantly. Should I add network-manager in start up program list? How can I format my answer to show like your "dmesg | grep wlan"?

Comment: The network-manager should be activated in the startup programs. If this doesn't help, try my suggestion in the answer below with the upstart script, perhaps this will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a workaround.

Create a Upstart file in the folder "/etc/init/startup-network-reset.conf".

The content should be:

```
description "Network restart at system startup"

start on (started network-interface
          or started network-manager
          or started networking)
stop on runlevel [!2345]

script
  sudo -u root service network-manager restart
end script
```

Perhaps an delay before restarting with sleep should be added.

For further details to the Upstart functions look at this page: http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/

Comment: Still a strange thing happens after the same interval (about 5 minutes). I'm disconnected / reconnected. After that everything it's OK. It's not very embarrassing, but I have no idea why it happens.

Answer (score 0):

seems, you forgot to chekc the button on the very first window on setup of your wifi-connection.

This is just a small error, which you can correct manually in your settings.
Therefore, go to your menue. There go to system-preferences and there go to network-connections.

There select your wifi-connection and edit it.

There, in the very first window, you see an option to be checked saying:

"automaticly connect to this network, if present"

Below that you see a second option saying:

"allow all users to use this network"

Both of these options have to be checked. If you did not check them, then set the check there and save these changes.

That's just it.

Greetings

Comment: Both options are checked.